# HTML has 2 forms, but document.forms only finds 1

Tags: javascript, html, forms

UPDATE: my own mistake. I should have used  `document.getElementById("auxInputImageForm")`Thank you for every comment.

I have 2 forms in my HTML (`auxInputImageForm` and `myFormID`):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding:0px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red; padding:0px;">
       <div id="methodDiv">
        <form id="auxInputImageForm">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type=file name=file style="width:190px; margin-top:5px;padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
            <input id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type=submit value=Upload style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:60px">
        </form> 
      </div>
  </div


  <div class="col-md-5" style="padding:0px;">
    <form id="myFormId">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type=file name=file style="width:190px; margin-top:5px;padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
        <input id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type=submit value=Upload style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:60px">
    </form> 
  </div>
</div
```

However, `document.forms` only returns `myFormID`. Below is the console.log(document.forms):
[image]

Also, I tried `document.getElementById("auxInputImage")`, but it returns null.

Is there a different javascript function I can use or is there something wrong with the code? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It's `document.getElementById("auxInputImageForm")` and that's the methods you should be using, not `document.forms`

Comment: works for me: http://jsbin.com/daxusuz/edit?html,js,console,output. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, try `document.getElementById("auxInputImageForm")` but not `document.getElementById("auxInputImage")`

Comment: Nothing wrong here, well a missing `>` on the end tag `</div` right before `<div class="col-md-5" style="padding:0px;">`

Comment: Why not using: 
`document.getElementsByTagName("form")`
Works for me:
https://plnkr.co/edit/NQbcPOdTLfQBl784krFE?p=preview

Comment: And `document.forms` does work: https://jsfiddle.net/7ntqk1wr/

Comment: @adeneo Voted to close this one as off topic/can't be reproduced

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in your html, have a closer look at this part:

```
         </form> 
      </div>
  </div   <!-- not closed, missing (>) -->
```

This is repeated twice in your current post. Correct this and `document.forms` works as expected.

```js
console.log(document.forms.length)
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red; padding:0px;">
  <div id="methodDiv">
    <form id="auxInputImageForm">
      <input class="btn btn-default" type=file name=file style="width:190px; margin-top:5px;padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
      <input id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type=submit value=Upload style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:60px">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- added (>) -->
<div class="col-md-5" style="padding:0px;">
  <form id="myFormId">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type=file name=file style="width:190px; margin-top:5px;padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
    <input id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type=submit value=Upload style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:60px">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery to run you code, I hasn't this problem

[doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5yEv.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8roWY.png)

can you copy you js code to problem